# i am trying to make regex for this type of string " (hello(world)) "

Tags: regex

i am trying to make regex for this type of string `(hello(world))` 
i made this regular expression `\([a-zA-Z]\([a-zA-Z])*\)\)` but it gives error.... what should i have to do to make it work properly....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regular expressions, brackets are a special character. If you want to match them literally, you need to escape them with a backslash: `\(`. *Edit*: looks like you escaped most of them, but it wasn't code formatted in your question. Fixed that, and there was only one missing escaped `)`.

You also are missing a quantifier (in this case another `*` or a `+` would work) that would enable it match your string, and the one you've got there is in the wrong position. This should work for you:

```
\([a-zA-Z]*\([a-zA-Z]*\)\)
```

Here's a regex101 to play around with: https://regex101.com/r/kQ0xT0/1

You can also use the `/i` case-insensitive modifier with most regex languages - this lets you just write `[a-z]` instead of `[a-zA-Z]`. See https://regex101.com/r/pT9kV1/1

Comment: A slightly more compact regex would be `\([A-z]+\([A-z]+\)\)`.

Comment: \\([a-zA-Z]*\\([a-zA-Z]*\\)\\) this is working correctly